# Multiple Calender with on single page for each month with event color for each date

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am looking for a calendar control which allow be to do a calendar as below so that it colour code each day based on event date.

Let assume based on below example i have event as

```
> Event Name: Event One 
> Start Date: 15-02-2019
> End Date: 18-02-2019
> Color Code: #ff0

> Event Name: Event Two
> Start Date: 25-02-2019
> End Date: 28-02-2019
> Color Code: #9ff

> Event Name: Event Three
> Start Date: 28-02-2019
> End Date: 28-02-2019
> Color Code: #g60
```

I found one [calendar](https://www.cssscript.com/create-simple-event-calendar-javascript-caleandar-js/) which seems to me as prospect but it seems difficult as i am not a JavaScript guy.

I would like to know can i turn this Calendar into what i a looking for or it can be done using different calendar plugin

[image]

https://codepen.io/kashmiriguide/pen/Erwdpp?editors=1010

any pointers would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

All calendar plugins (as any other plugin) will have a documentation and an explanation on how to use it. I highly doubt that there is a specific calendar plugin to do **exactly** what you want to do and just that, specially if you don't know the basics about Javascript. I'd recommend you to get some knowledge about it first to understand how it can be used.

When that is accomplished, I usually use [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/), it is highly programmable.

Comment: Plugin which i shared doesnt have much documentation and regarding fullCalendar thatwill show mulitple events based, but problem with my requirement is that i have to show 12 calendar controls on 1 pages 1 for each month so full calendar will be quite heavy

Answer (score 0):

Something like https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ might do the trick. Each day on the calendar has a specific class and some data attributes. You can combine those to create some CSS selectors & style accordingly if that works for you.